# How do I install an iOS app onto hardware when testing via Appium in a Selenium Grid?

Tags: ios, selenium, grid, webdriver, appium

I'm setting up a system to run automated tests on real devices connected to a Selenium Grid. Here's my set up.

I have an iPhone connected to a mac. The mac is running an Appium server that is registered with a Selenium Grid. I'm using Java to write Selenium WebDriver tests, which will be executed on a different machine (via Jenkins) and use the grid to select an appropriate device. So from my tests, I have no direct access to this mac or the iPhone.

My question is how do I remotely install new versions of my app onto the iPhone prior to testing?

I was hoping that I could supply appium with a URL to a .zip or .ipa file, and that it would download and install the app. That sort of thing is hinted at in various blogs, but I can't find any documentation on how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one link that shows how to build and deploy apps to real iOS devices:
https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/ios-deploy.md

You could execute the building and deploying via Jenkins on any of the machines that you use.

After that, you just need to specify the "bundle id" in your tests when you build the required  capabilities, as shown in this (python) example: https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/sample-code/examples/python/simple_real_device.py

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that I could pass a Jenkins URL into appium, and have it fetch and install the app automatically. The machines running appium are dumb Selenium Grid nodes, rather than Jenkins nodes.